# Checking if an array is a subset of another array (but checking against a property)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, object

I know this works (returns true)

```
var arr1 = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3];

var isSuperset = arr2.every(function (val) { return arr1.indexOf(val) >= 0; });
```

However say array1 consists of objects, and I want to check array2 against a certain property of the object:

```
var object1 = {name:'one'}
var object2 = {name:'two'}
var object3 = {name:'three'}

var arr1 = [object1,object2,object3];
var arr2 = ['one','two'];
var isSuperset = arr2.every(function (val) { return arr1.indexOf(val) >= 0; });
```

How can I ensure the every function checks against the name property?

Comment: `var arr3 = arr1.map(function(val) { return val.name; })` and in the predicte of `arr2.every`, use `return arr3.indexOf(val) >= 0;`.

Comment: Oh, you were faster, same solution, upvote

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var object1 = {name: 'one'};
var object2 = {name: 'two'};
var object3 = {name: 'three'};

var arr1 = [object1,object2,object3];
var arr2 = ['one','two'];

// solution
var names = arr1.map(function(obj) { 
  return obj.name; 
});

var isSuperset = arr2.every(function(val) { 
  return names.indexOf(val) >= 0;
});

alert(isSuperset);
```